# While calling the create envilope API we are getting the error

Tags: docusignapi

While calling the create envilope API we are getting the error

```
{
  "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_MISSING_ENTITLEMENT_CREATE_EMBEDDEDRECIPIENTSTARTURL",
  "message": "The sender does not have required entitlement and is not allowed to set EmbeddedRecipientStartURL for the user"
}
```

Request url

/v2/accounts/8017620c-2355-481c-a7b2-50b645d40a52/envelopes

Request body (envelope)

```
{
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1864177648",
            "name": "powerpoint press.pptx",
            "fileExtension": "pptx",
            "matchBoxes": [],
            "documentFields": [],
            "documentBase64": ""
        }
    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "excludedDocuments": [],
                "name": "Mehraj",
                "email": "mehraj@mydomain.com",
                "signingGroupUsers": [],
                "recipientId": "cbd343d7-a735-4846-8138-243ec7b31348",
                "socialAuthentications": [],
                "clientUserId": "0e670c86-aa1a-4149-9ce6-9c27dd76d3b0",
                "embeddedRecipientStartURL": "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                "customFields": [],
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "recipientAttachments": []
            }
        ],
        "agents": [],
        "editors": [],
        "intermediaries": [],
        "carbonCopies": [],
        "certifiedDeliveries": [],
        "inPersonSigners": []
    },
    "eventNotification": {
        "url": "https://mysite.mydomain.com/root/api/docusign/webhook/eventnotification",
        "loggingEnabled": "true",
        "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
        "envelopeEvents": [
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "delivered"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "declined"
            },
            {
                "envelopeEventStatusCode": "voided"
            }
        ],
        "recipientEvents": [
            {
                "recipientEventStatusCode": "Sent"
            },
            {
                "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
            },
            {
                "recipientEventStatusCode": "Declined"
            },
            {
                "recipientEventStatusCode": "AuthenticationFailed"
            },
            {
                "recipientEventStatusCode": "AutoResponded"
            }
        ],
        "useSoapInterface": "false",
        "includeCertificateWithSoap": "false",
        "signMessageWithX509Cert": "false",
        "includeDocuments": "false",
        "includeEnvelopeVoidReason": "true",
        "includeTimeZone": "true",
        "includeSenderAccountAsCustomField": "true",
        "includeDocumentFields": "true",
        "includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false"
    },
    "templateRoles": [],
    "compositeTemplates": [],
    "status": "created",
    "emailSubject": "powerpoint press",
    "recipientsLock": "true"
}
```

** I have removed the documentBase64 contennts to make the post shorter **

In demo environment everything works fine, but in the production environment we are getting the specified error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the embedded start URL is a paid add-on feature.  Your production account probably didn't include this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your envelope before I can give you a complete answer but this page will likely shed light on what you maybe missing:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/reference/sending-group/rules-for-createandsendenvelope-and-createenvelope/

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you, 
The document you mentioned does not mention this error,
I have updated my question to include the envelope body.
Please take a look.